# Makefiles and structures in C

Tags: c, struct, makefile

EDIT: To try and make things easier for the kind souls trying to help me, here are a couple links that should make things more clear:

[Pre-makefile repl](https://repl.it/@chadathin/pre-makefile-HW6)

[Post-makefile repl](https://repl.it/@chadathin/post-makefile-HW6)

A little background on the assignment: We are supposed to take a program we wrote last week and break up the separate functions into their own files and use a makefile to compile and link and all that stuff. This is my original program (basically, it reads a file of `name number` and stores them in a struct, then uses the command line arguments to search for a name).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct _data {
  char* name;
  long number;
};

int SCAN(FILE *(*input)) {
  int lines = 0;
  char word[50];
  long num = 0;
  while (1) {
    fscanf(*input,"%s %ld",word, &num);
    lines++;
    if (feof(*input)) break;
  }
  return lines;
}

struct _data *LOAD(FILE *input, int size) {
  char* line = NULL;
  size_t len = 0;
  int i=0;
  rewind(input);
  struct _data *book = calloc(size,sizeof(struct _data));

  for (i = 0;i<size;i++) {
    getline(&line, &len, input);
    book[i].name = calloc(len+1,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(book[i].name,strtok(line," "));
    book[i].number = atoi(strtok(NULL, " "));
  }
  return book;
}

void SEARCH(struct _data *BlackBook, char *name, int size) {
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<size;i++) {
    if (strcmp(name,BlackBook[i].name) == 0) {
      printf("*******************************************\n");
      printf("The name was found at the %d entry.\n",i+1);
      printf("*******************************************\n");
      break;
    }
    //If we reach the end of the array and name was not found
    if (i == size-1) {
      printf("*******************************************\n");
      printf("The name was NOT found.\n");
      printf("*******************************************\n");
    }
  }
}

void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size) {
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<size;i++){
    free(BlackBook[i].name);
  }
  free(BlackBook);
}

//MAIN DRIVER ===================
int main(int argv, char** argc) {

  int size;
  char* filename = "hw5.data";

  FILE *input = fopen(filename,"r");

  size = SCAN(&input);

  struct _data *phone_book = LOAD(input,size);

  fclose(input);

  //Check a name is given. If so, search
  if (argv < 2) {
    printf("*******************************************\n");
    printf("* You must include a name to search for.  *\n");
    printf("*******************************************\n");
  } else {
    SEARCH(phone_book, argc[1], size);
  }

  FREE(phone_book,size);
  return 0;
}
```

When I make my makefile, I can get the `SCAN` and `LOAD` functions to work appropriately. But, when I try to put either `SEARCH` or `FREE` into their own files, my compiler freaks out and I get warnings like:

```
In file included from hw6-free.c:1:0:
hw6-free.h:9:18: warning: ‘struct _data’ declared inside parameter list
 void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size);
                  ^
hw6-free.h:9:18: warning: its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want
hw6-free.c:3:18: warning: ‘struct _data’ declared inside parameter list
 void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size) {
                  ^
hw6-free.c:3:6: error: conflicting types for ‘FREE’
 void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size) {
      ^
In file included from hw6-free.c:1:0:
hw6-free.h:9:6: note: previous declaration of ‘FREE’ was here
 void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size);
      ^
hw6-free.c: In function ‘FREE’:
hw6-free.c:6:5: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct _data’
     free(BlackBook[i].name);
     ^
hw6-free.c:6:19: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct _data’
     free(BlackBook[i].name);
                   ^
Makefile:20: recipe for target 'hw6-free.o' failed
make: *** [hw6-free.o] Error 1
```

And reading through it, it looks like the fact my program takes a struct as an argument is my main problem? My 'post-makefile' program looks like:

```
#include "hw6-main.h"

int main(int argv, char** argc) {

  int size;
  char* filename = "hw5.data";

  FILE *input = fopen(filename,"r");

  size = SCAN(&input);

  struct _data *phone_book = LOAD(input,size);

  fclose(input);

  //Check a name is given. If so, search
  if (argv < 2) {
    printf("*******************************************\n");
    printf("* You must include a name to search for.  *\n");
    printf("*******************************************\n");
  } else {
    SEARCH(phone_book, argc[1], size);
  }

  FREE(phone_book,size);
  return 0;
}
```

And my makefile looks like:

```
DEP = hw6-scan.o hw6-load.o hw6-search.o hw6-free.o hw6-main.o
HDR = hw6-scan.h hw6-load.h hw6-search.h hw6-free.h hw6-main.h
NAME = output

all: $(NAME)

output: $(DEP) $(HDR)
    gcc $(DEP) $(HDR) -o $(NAME)

hw6-scan.o: hw6-scan.c
    gcc -c hw6-scan.c

hw6-load.o: hw6-load.c
    gcc -c hw6-load.c

hw6-search.o: hw6-search.c
    gcc -c hw6-search.c

hw6-free.o: hw6-free.c
    gcc -c hw6-free.c

hw6-main.o: hw6-main.c
    gcc -c hw6-main.c

clean:
    rm *.o *.gch *.out output testfile
```

As an example, my `hw6-free.c` and `hw6-free.h` look like:

```
#include "hw6-free.h"

void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size) {
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<size;i++){
    free(BlackBook[i].name);
  }
  free(BlackBook);
}
```

and

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size);
```

respectively.

And, finally, I defined the struct in the `hw6-load.h` file, along with a function prototype. Is that also a problem? Should I be defining it elsewhere?

I am SO SORRY for the long post, but I have been working on the for 10 hours and I'm about to throw my computer of a cliff.

THANK YOU FOR YOUR HELP STACK OVERFLOW!

Comment: It's not so much where you define your structures, it's where you include them.  If you put your structures in a header file `hw6-load.h` then you must add `#include "hw6-load.h"` at (or near) the top of _every file_ that refers in any way to any of those structures.  Else, how can the compiler know what the structures contain or how big they are? (for advanced users there are circumstances where you can avoid the `#include` but it's not worth worrying about for programs of this size)

Comment: Just so I understand correctly: Should I be putting the `#include hw6-load.h` in the `.c` or `.h` files? I tried putting it in each `.h` file for the corresponding `.c` file that references the structure, but now I just get an error for conflicting data types and "redefinition of struct data. Originally defined here" for each instance in which I included it. So, it _sounds_ like it thinks I'm redefining the structure, instead of just trying to refer back to the _one_ I defined in the first place.

Comment: You are trying to do too many new things at once. Write a simple program, a `main()` and a couple of functions. Then split one of the functions out into a source `foo.c` and a header `foo.h`. Get that working before you attempt anything more complicated.

Comment: I did. That’s my main problem. I started with a small program and everything worked well! Then I did this larger program the exact same way, and it doesn’t work all the sudden. And I realize the point of the assignment is to get us comfortable with makefiles, but I totally agree; this is so convoluted for a program of this size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an in-depth explanation of the details. It might be a bit too much, but if you keep reading, you may get a much deeper understanding of the language than if you just learn to write code that your compiler is ok with.

---

**You are using your `struct` before you have declared it**. Keep in mind that an `#include` is just a fancy way of telling your compiler: "Please, paste the contents of this .h file at this spot." The result of this pasting must read like valid code to the compiler.

It is true that the compiler's error message looks a bit weird. It certainly does not say "You used `struct _data` before you declared it". The reason for this is, that structs are implicitly declared at their first use. So, if you declare a variable with `struct foo* bar;` and the compiler has never seen a `struct foo` before, it will immediately consider `struct foo` as being declared, and a pointer variable to this `struct foo` of unknown size and shape will be defined. Likewise, when your compiler sees the function declaration

```
void foo(struct bar *baz);
```

it sees that it doesn't know a `struct bar` and implicitly declares one. Because this struct declaration happens inside a function declaration, the resulting type is declared local to the declaration at hand. **As such, it is impossible for calling code to pass an argument of the correct type into this function, or even to implement the function in a separate statement**. Such a function declaration is always useless. This is what the warning text "its scope is only this definition or declaration, which is probably not what you want" means: The compiler writers knew that such a declaration is bullshit, but it's legal C as far as the standard is concerned, so they compile it, but warn about it.

---

Ok, let's get to the actual error message. As the compiler tells you, the `struct _data` was only declared for the function declaration at hand. When your compiler later sees the function implementation, it stumbles across the undeclared `struct _data` a second time. Again, it implicitly declares a local struct type which is distinct from the previously implicitly declared type. Because those two implicitly declared types are distinct, so are the signatures of the declared functions. However, C mandates that a function can only have one signature, so the compiler produces the error "conflicting types for ‘FREE’".

You can try this out with this simple code:

```
void foo(struct bar* baz);    //warning: local declaration of `struct bar`
void foo(struct bar* baz);    //repeated warning + conflicting types error
```

---

So, how to fix this?

Simple. Declare your `struct` before you use it. That way you avoid its implicit declaration. The following code compiles fine:

```
struct bar;    //global declaration of `struct bar`
void foo(struct bar* baz);    //`struct bar` is known and the global declaration is used
void foo(struct bar* baz);    //same as above, because this uses the same global declaration of `struct bar`, this redeclaration of `foo()` is ok
```

The declaration of the `struct _data` belongs into the header file that declares the functions which use `struct _data` as arguments.

---

Idiomatic declarations

Usually, types are declared with a `typedef`. This allows the code to omit the `struct` keyword when declaring variables. This takes one of two idiomatic forms:

- To have a type with public members (pure data, no object in the OO sense), put the `struct` *definition* into the header:

  ```
  typedef struct foo    //`struct foo` is declared implicitly here
  {    //it is also defined (= inner details are given) right here
      int bar;    //its member variables are defined
  } baz;    //this concludes the typedef, giving `struct foo` a second name
  //`struct foo` and `baz` are now equivalent.
  ```

  Usually, the two names will be the same or very similar, so the cleaned definition looks like this:

  ```
  typedef struct foo {
      int bar;
  } foo;

  //declarations of the functions that use `struct foo`
  ...
  ```
- If the type is an object that should keep its data members to itself, the declaration and definitions are split like this:

  Inside foo.h:

  ```
  typedef struct foo foo;    //declare that `struct foo` == `foo` exists, but don't give details

  //declare the functions working on a `foo`
  void foo_bim(foo* me);
  void foo_bam(foo* me, ...);
  ...
  ```

  Inside foo.c:

  ```
  #include "foo.h"    //so that the compiler may check that the function declarations in the header agree with the implementations in this file

  struct foo {    //define the size and shape of `struct foo` == `foo`
      int bar;
  };
  //now only this file knows how a `struct foo` actually looks like

  //implement the member functions of `foo`
  void foo_bim(foo* me) {
      ...
  }

  void foo_bam(foo* me, ...) {
      ...
  }
  ```

Note that the `typedef ... non-struct-name;` is purely optional in both cases, and there are quite a few programmers who want to see the `struct` keyword wherever a `struct` is used (like a certain Mr. Torvalds). These programmers simply leave off the `typedef ... non-struct-name;` part, otherwise they use the idioms above in the same way. I have described the full-featured version here, to ensure that you'll not be surprised when you first see the `typedef` construct.

Comment: Wow. You just filled in SO MANY gaps our instructor left out. Not only with `structs` but with the organization and functionality of makefiles in general. Our instructor was like, "This is how professionals do it, so you better have a good handle on this stuff." One 45-minute lecture later and that was the extent of our makefile education. Thank you so much! I also think I was getting a structure _definition_ and structure _declaration_ confused. Declaring it before it's used is _kind of_ like using a function prototype; the compiler sees it and says, "We're cool, bro."

Comment: Nice answer, but I'd disagree with `typedef` being idiomatic. There are many codebases which try to be quite careful with "polluting" the type name namespace, which is essentially what typedef does. In whole UNIX/POSIX there is just a handful of typedefs.

Comment: @larkey Yes, its some kind of a religious debate. I showed the "full featured" declarations to preclude surprise & confusion when people like the OP first see the `typedef`. I hope, the way I explained it, people will easily understand the meaning when the `typedef` is missing. Had I done it the other way round, the meaning of the typedefed version would be totally confusing at first. -- That said, you are right, there are large code bases that avoid the use of `typedef`, the most notorious being the Linux kernel.

Comment: @larkey Btw, I have added a paragraph to the end now, saying that the `typedef` can be, and frequently is dropped. Hope you like it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you did.  But to step back: keep clear in your mind the difference between *declarations* and *definitions*.  A *declaration* shows a variable or function signature, but does not create any variables of that type or implement that function.  A *definition* declares a new variable (of some type) or implements a function.  A *declaration* of a type just states that it exists (basically).  A *definition* of a type shows its structure and members.

So, a definition of your type would be:

```
struct _data {
  char* name;
  long number;
};
```

And a declaration of a function would be:

```
void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size);
```

and a definition of a function would be:

```
void FREE(struct _data *BlackBook, int size) {
  int i;
  for (i=0;i<size;i++){
    free(BlackBook[i].name);
  }
  free(BlackBook);
}
```

So here're the rules:

1. Only `#include` header files in other files, never `#include` source files.
2. If a type is needed in more than one file, put its *definition* into a header file and `#include` that header file in all source files that use the type.
3. If a function is used in more than one file, put the *declaration* of that function into a header file and `#include` that header file in all the source files that use the function, including the source file containing the *definition* of the function.

If you follow these rules you'll never run into duplicate definitions at link time: you can't have duplicate definitions if you link each source file only one time and no included file contains a definition.

Type declarations can be useful, and breaking some of these rules can be useful, but for the work you're doing that's probably not worth worrying about.

Comment: Worth noting on the other side, if a function is only used in one file, (as say, a helper function, _viz_ it is useless to declare it in the header,) then it should be `static`, which means it is only defined in a single compilation unit. This reduces namespace pollution and allows the compiler to optimise it much more.

Comment: Right. As I understand it, (for example) if I have `funcs.c` and `funcs.h`...I _declare_ my functions and `#include "funcs.h"` in my `.c` file. Then, I `#include` any headers I need to compile the `.c` file in the `.h` file, along with a function prototype. Correct?

Comment: Nitpick: Your first code example is the structure *definition*, which also happens to declare the structure. A pure declaration would be `struct _data;`. Not really that useful on its own, it is typically enclosed in a typedef (`typedef struct _data _data;`) which works as a forward declaration of the incomplete type (= enough to declare functions taking pointers to `_data` in your headers, but no details = all the client code needs to know). The full definition is then placed inside the `.c` file that implements all the methods of `_data`.

Comment: Yes... the "rules" are really just suggestions and there can be good reasons to violate each of them, but given the experience level of the OP I didn't want confuse things.  I was talking about declarations/definitions of _variables_ not types (since the question is about multiple definitions in the linker) but I guess I probably confused things by avoiding discussing types.  If we're going to be discussing "style" such as using `static` my first advice would be to not uppercase all function names--that's something you'll never see in "real code"--only macros :)

Comment: I reworked this to ignore variables since global variables should be avoided in general and don't appear in the question anyway.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica A `struct bar;` is definitely useful on its own, even w/o a typedef. The typedef has no effect on the forward declaration and you can just as well hide implementation with a forward declared struct foo.

Comment: @larkey Yeah, right. In thinking deeper about this, I realized this as well. The `typedef` version is the idiomatic one to me, and I've never seen a `struct _data` on its own, yet. But I'll remember that its possible and useful.

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica yeah, it's just something that jumps to my eye, coming from a Unix perspective. Many opaque or partly opaque structures such as `struct stockaddr_storage` :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to put header of struct declaration at top of files which uses it and be sure you’ve imported the file which contains struct declaration.